# this keyword inside nested function of object literal

Tags: javascript

```
var c = {
    name: 'The c object',
    log: function() {

        console.log(this);

}
```

In this example `this` keyword points to the containing object "c"
   `c.log()` returns `Object {name: "The c object", log: function}`

```
 var c = {
    name: 'The c object',
    log: function() {

        this.name = 'Updated c object';
        console.log(this);

}
```

Here we can see that this still points to the c object as
   `c.log()` returns `Object {name: "Updated c object", log: function}`

However in the following code:

```
    var c = {
        name: 'The c object',
        log: function() {
            this.name = 'Updated c object';
            console.log(this);

            var setname = function(newname) {
                this.name = newname;   
            }
            setname('Updated again! The c object');
            console.log(this);
      }
 }
```

If we type `c.log()`, instead of setting the name to "Updated again! The c object", it created an object in window with that same property.

Specific question I have is: the first `this` keyword is inside a function but doesn't point to the global object, why does the `this` keyword in the `setname` function point the global object?

Comment: try `setname.call(this, 'Updated again! The c object');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In this example this keyword points to the containing object "c"

No, it doesn't. `this` doesn't point anywhere until the function is **called** and its value depends on **how** it was called, not on where it was defined.

> Here we can see that this still points to the c object as  c.log() returns Object {name: "Updated c object", log: function}

It points to `c` because you called `c.log()`. It was called in the context of `c`.

> If we type c.log(), instead of setting the name to "Updated again! The c object", it created an object in window with that same property.

You are calling `setname('Updated again! The c object');`. There is no context (`nothing_here.setname`), there is no `new` keyword, there is no `call` or `apply` method and you are not in strict mode. Therefore it is called in the context of the default object which, in a browser context, is `window`.